# Flutter: aligning TextFormField and DropdownButtonFormField in same row

Tags: flutter, forms, alignment

In my form I have a TextFormField and DropdownButtonFormField in the same row. If I set CrossAxisAlignment.end for the row the alignment normally works but once the validation triggers for just one of the fields it completely breaks.

[image]

I tried with CrossAxisAlignment.baseline and the closest result was with TextBaseline.alphabetic, but there is still some little difference between the two fields (both before and after validation)

[image]

Here is my code. How can I align these two fields both before and after validation?

```
Form(
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          Expanded(
              child: TextFormField(
              autofillHints: const [AutofillHints.telephoneNumber],
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Phone',
                floatingLabelStyle:
                    const TextStyle(color: Color(0x99000000)),
              ),
              initialValue: model.phone,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
              onSaved: (value) {
                model.phone = value;
              },
              validator: (value) {
                return (value == null || value.isEmpty) ? "Required field" : null;
              },
            )
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 10),
          Expanded(
            child: DropdownButtonFormField<int>(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Participants',
                  floatingLabelStyle:
                    const TextStyle(color: Color(0x99000000)),
                ),
                items: model.participantsList(),
              onChanged: (value) {
                  model.participants = value;
              },
            )
          ),
        ],
      ),
      TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'Notes',
          floatingLabelStyle:
              const TextStyle(color: Color(0x99000000)),
        ),
        onSaved: (value) {
          model.notes = value;
        },
        textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can use another widget which represent error message.
Here is updated code:

```
//Update this errorString in validation 
String errorString = "";

Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: TextFormField(
                  autofillHints: const [AutofillHints.telephoneNumber],
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Phone',
                    floatingLabelStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0x99000000)),
                  ),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    // Save the value to your model
                  },
                  validator: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      errorString = value == null || value.isEmpty
                          ? "Required field"
                          : "";
                    });
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 10),
              Expanded(
                child: DropdownButtonFormField<int>(
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Participants',
                    floatingLabelStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0x99000000)),
                  ),
                  items: const [], // Replace with your actual list of items
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    // Save the value to your model
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
//Here, to show your error. Add textStyle and other properties based on your requirement.
          Align(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft, child: Text(errorString)),
          TextFormField(
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Notes',
              floatingLabelStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0x99000000)),
            ),
            onSaved: (value) {
              // Save the value to your model
            },
            textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              // Trigger validation before saving data
              if (_formKey.currentState?.validate() ?? false) {
                _formKey.currentState?.save();
                // Save your form data here
              }
            },
            child: const Text('Save'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
```